# Script for angular-google-analytics is not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, google-analytics

I try to use angular-google-analytics for tracking traffic. I'm using angular 1.4.8.
Version of angular-google-analytics is 1.1.9. I included it in my bower.json file and linked script in my template.razr file as a showed below:

```
    <script src='bower_components/angular-google-analytics/dist/angular-google-analytics.min.js'></script>
```

In main module of the app I did dependency injection as below in my .coffee file:

```
app = angular.module('speedUpApp', [
'angular-google-analytics',
'ngAnimate'
'ngCookies'
'ngSanitize'
'ngTouch'
'pascalprecht.translate'
'ui.router'
'ngMaterial'
'ngMap'
'slick'
'nl2br'
'lodash'
'angular-images-loaded'
'ui.select2'
'angular-iscroll'
'smoothScroll'
'angular-inview',
'dibari.angular-ellipsis'
'ngFileUpload'
])
```

First dependency is just angular-google-analytics. In spite of those steps after running my local server in my browser console I receive an error:

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module speedUpApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-google-analytics due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-google-analytics' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Now I cannot recognize the problem, because I declared the angular-google-analytics module dependency and dependency injection too, despite of it, I still encounter this error. Any help?